# Path followed by centre of mass of a ball when ball breaks up in two parts due to internal stresses

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, momentum

A ball was moving along a parabola and it breaks up into two parts.

How can I say that the centre of mass will follow the same parabola ?
I know that ( for simplicity I am assuming that the ball is made up of just two particles which break up due to internal stresses) so as acceleration of both the particles is same ($g$) so the C.O.M. acceleration is also ( $a \,\ = \,\ g$) .....equation (1).

Now as there is no external force acting in the horizontal direction, so by $$v_{C.O.M.} = \frac{ M_1V_1 + M_2 V_2}{m_1+m_2}$$ momentum is conserved along horizontal, so the centre of mass velocity along the horizontal should be the same (result 2).

But now still I need to show that the centre of mass will follow the same parabola as before the separation of the two particles of the ball ???

Comment: At any time interval the COM would be in the same position as it should have, if the ball didn't break. So, it follows the same parabola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the system has not been subjected to any external force other than gravity. As a result, the ball breaking into 2 parts due to internal stresses will have its center of mass unmoved.

The entire system, in this case, the ball has not experienced any net external force other than gravity. So there is no net external force acting on the C.O.M. of the ball other than gravity.

So the C.O.M. of the ball itself acts as a body in projectile motion. And just as a projectile falling under gravity without experiencing any drag follows a parabolic path, so does the C.O.M. of the ball in this case.

**EDIT**: As I have mentioned in my previous comment, under the action of gravity, the ball follows a particular parabolic path.

[image]

In this case, the ball is given an initial velocity by the thrower i.e. the thrower gives it some kinetic energy and the ball does work as it rises up converting K.E. to P.E.

I hope this is clear. Because this concept is being used when I am saying "entire work done by COM must be due to gravity". Consider the part of the motion where the ball is falling. There only the gravity is acting on the ball. Now gravity being a conservative force, net work in the ball falling down = net work done in the ball rising up. In other words, net work in a conservative field is 0. But if you consider a small portion of the parabolic path, the ball is being displaced due to gravity and so the ball is converting its potential energy into kinetic energy and work to change its displacement.

Now if the C.O.M. has a movement as a result of which the parabolic path it traces is no longer the same as the original parabola, then it will be like:

[image]

Now under gravity it should follow, say, path 2. And you say that it shifts to path 1. In that case there is a displacement and the work done in displacing the C.O.M. requires force by an external agent. Now this cannot be gravity, for gravity does not allow for such displacement, it prefers path 2. So there must be some other force. But there isn't one, as mentioned earlier. So such change in parabolic path is not possible.

As for your 2nd comment, the gravity is doing work on the C.O.M. as gravity is a conservative force. If you could take air drag into account, you might well get it clear that the ball does work in changing its displacement for the field then would be non-conservative.

Comment: Ok!!taken that the velocity of the COM did not change but that only means the COM will follow a parabola //so how can we say that this parabola will be the same as the original parabola

Comment: I was first thinking that as COM velocity did not change so that would mean its position didn't change either // but it may happen that COM position could be displaced parallely so that its COM position changed but it's velocity vector remained the same or the popular statement given in all answers here COM velocity did not change.

Comment: Or in short I still want to know how can I say the COM position also  didn't change in the infinitesimal time period just before and after collision.

Comment: Movement of C.O.M. is possible only when an additional external force acts on the body(C.O.M.). But here only gravity works on the C.O.M. So its movement is guided by gravity. Say, as you are saying, the C.O.M. has a movement as a result of which the parabolic path it traces is no longer the same as the original parabola. In that case, for that displacement, the C.O.M. must do some work and work = force $\times $ displacement. But no external force acts on it other than gravity. So entire work done by C.O.M. must be due to gravity. So C.O.M. traces the original parabola only. Hope it helps

Comment: What do you mean by -"In this case for that displacement the COM must do some wok ...so entire work done by COM must be due to gravity".can you please elaborate that a little bit.

Comment: Also on what object or thing is the COM doing work on??as I don't think it can do work on itself!!!like it can do work on earth(even though that will be negligible) or something else.can you explain this more??

Comment: I have updated my answer with answers to your comments. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's Third Law tells us that the momentum imparted to fragment #1 is equal and opposite to the momentum imparted to #2.  So if I take as my *system* all the atoms of the original object, we see that the momentum of the *system* hasn't changed at all.

Answer (score 0):

By Newton's 3rd law, the force on each component is equal and opposite which means the acceleration of the center of mass has not changed (because there is no net external force other than gravity) and also, by conservation of momentum the CM's velocity has not changed due to the splitting.

You can conserve momentum for the tiny interval of time starting from just before the collision up until just after the collision, because in that infinitesimal time interval the non-impulsive gravitational force imparts no significant momentum to the bodies. The only force that matters then, is the impulsive force, which imparts equal and opposite impulse on these two bodies keeping the center of mass velocity unaffected.

Since the velocity and acceleration of the CM are unchanged by this splitting apart, it continues to move as if nothing has taken place, that is, along that same parabola.